# Vector Math with System.Numerics

Tags: c#, vb.net, math, vector-graphics, system.numerics

I have the following code which rotates vectors and always keeps the result in the positive x,y,z plane.
I want to re-factor the code to use the System.Numerics type Vector3 and Matrix4x4.
Could somebody help me translate it.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim rotation As Vector = New Vector(45, 0, -90)
        Dim delta As Vector = New Vector(10, 10, 10)
        Dim result As Vector = InverseVector(delta, rotation)
    End Sub

    Private Function InverseVector(ByVal _delta As Vector, ByVal _rotation As Vector) As Vector
        Dim vChange As New Vector(0, 0, 0)
        Dim matX(2, 2) As Single
        Dim matY(2, 2) As Single
        Dim matZ(2, 2) As Single
        Dim negativeFactor As Int32 = 1
        Dim dDeterminate As Single
        Dim matAdjoin(2, 2) As Single
        Dim matTranspose(2, 2) As Single
        Dim matInverse(2, 2) As Single

        If _delta.X < 0 Or _delta.Y < 0 Or _delta.Z < 0 Then
            negativeFactor = -1
        End If

        Dim dRadians As Single

        dRadians = 0.0174532D * _rotation.X

        'Load the X Matrix
        matX(0, 0) = 1
        matX(0, 1) = 0
        matX(0, 2) = 0
        matX(1, 0) = 0
        matX(1, 1) = CDec(Math.Round(Math.Cos(dRadians), 4))
        matX(1, 2) = CDec(Math.Round(Math.Sin(dRadians), 4) * -1)
        matX(2, 0) = 0
        matX(2, 1) = CDec(Math.Round(Math.Sin(dRadians), 4))
        matX(2, 2) = CDec(Math.Round(Math.Cos(dRadians), 4))

        'Load up the Y Matrix
        dRadians = 0.0174532D * _rotation.Y
        matY(0, 0) = CDec(Math.Round(Math.Cos(dRadians), 4))
        matY(0, 1) = 0
        matY(0, 2) = CDec(Math.Round(Math.Sin(dRadians), 4))
        matY(1, 0) = 0
        matY(1, 1) = 1
        matY(1, 2) = 0
        matY(2, 0) = CDec(Math.Round(Math.Sin(dRadians), 4) * -1)
        matY(2, 1) = 0
        matY(2, 2) = CDec(Math.Round(Math.Cos(dRadians), 4))

        'Load up the Z Matrix
        dRadians = 0.0174532D * _rotation.Z
        matZ(0, 0) = CDec(Math.Round(Math.Cos(dRadians), 4))
        matZ(0, 1) = CDec(Math.Round(Math.Sin(dRadians), 4) * -1)
        matZ(0, 2) = 0
        matZ(1, 0) = CDec(Math.Round(Math.Sin(dRadians), 4))
        matZ(1, 1) = CDec(Math.Round(Math.Cos(dRadians), 4))
        matZ(1, 2) = 0
        matZ(2, 0) = 0
        matZ(2, 1) = 0
        matZ(2, 2) = 1

        'multiply the two matrices
        Dim resultMatrix1(2, 2) As Single
        For i As Integer = 0 To 2
            For j As Integer = 0 To 2
                resultMatrix1(i, j) = matX(i, 0) * matY(0, j) +
                                       matX(i, 1) * matY(1, j) +
                                       matX(i, 2) * matY(2, j)
            Next
        Next

        'Now mutiply ResultMatrix with X matrix
        Dim resultMatrix2(2, 2) As Single
        For i As Integer = 0 To 2
            For j As Integer = 0 To 2
                resultMatrix2(i, j) = matZ(i, 0) * resultMatrix1(0, j) +
                                       matZ(i, 1) * resultMatrix1(1, j) +
                                       matZ(i, 2) * resultMatrix1(2, j)
            Next
        Next

        'Get determinate
        dDeterminate = (resultMatrix2(0, 0) * resultMatrix2(1, 1) * resultMatrix2(2, 2)) +
                       (resultMatrix2(0, 1) * resultMatrix2(1, 2) * resultMatrix2(2, 0)) +
                       (resultMatrix2(0, 2) * resultMatrix2(2, 1) * resultMatrix2(1, 0)) -
                       (resultMatrix2(0, 2) * resultMatrix2(1, 1) * resultMatrix2(2, 0)) -
                       (resultMatrix2(0, 1) * resultMatrix2(1, 0) * resultMatrix2(2, 2)) -
                       (resultMatrix2(0, 0) * resultMatrix2(1, 2) * resultMatrix2(2, 1))

        matAdjoin(0, 0) =
            ((resultMatrix2(1, 1) * resultMatrix2(2, 2)) - (resultMatrix2(1, 2) * resultMatrix2(2, 1))) * 1
        matAdjoin(0, 1) =
            ((resultMatrix2(1, 0) * resultMatrix2(2, 2)) - (resultMatrix2(1, 2) * resultMatrix2(2, 0))) * -1
        matAdjoin(0, 2) =
            ((resultMatrix2(1, 0) * resultMatrix2(2, 1)) - (resultMatrix2(1, 1) * resultMatrix2(2, 0))) * 1
        matAdjoin(1, 0) =
            ((resultMatrix2(0, 1) * resultMatrix2(2, 2)) - (resultMatrix2(0, 2) * resultMatrix2(2, 1))) * -1
        matAdjoin(1, 1) =
            ((resultMatrix2(0, 0) * resultMatrix2(2, 2)) - (resultMatrix2(0, 2) * resultMatrix2(2, 0))) * 1
        matAdjoin(1, 2) =
            ((resultMatrix2(0, 0) * resultMatrix2(2, 1)) - (resultMatrix2(0, 1) * resultMatrix2(2, 0))) * -1
        matAdjoin(2, 0) =
            ((resultMatrix2(0, 1) * resultMatrix2(1, 2)) - (resultMatrix2(0, 2) * resultMatrix2(1, 1))) * 1
        matAdjoin(2, 1) =
            ((resultMatrix2(0, 0) * resultMatrix2(1, 2)) - (resultMatrix2(0, 2) * resultMatrix2(1, 0))) * -1
        matAdjoin(2, 2) =
            ((resultMatrix2(0, 0) * resultMatrix2(1, 1)) - (resultMatrix2(0, 1) * resultMatrix2(1, 0))) * 1

        matTranspose(0, 0) = matAdjoin(0, 0)
        matTranspose(0, 1) = matAdjoin(1, 0)
        matTranspose(0, 2) = matAdjoin(2, 0)
        matTranspose(1, 0) = matAdjoin(0, 1)
        matTranspose(1, 1) = matAdjoin(1, 1)
        matTranspose(1, 2) = matAdjoin(2, 1)
        matTranspose(2, 0) = matAdjoin(0, 2)
        matTranspose(2, 1) = matAdjoin(1, 2)
        matTranspose(2, 2) = matAdjoin(2, 2)

        matInverse(0, 0) = matTranspose(0, 0) / dDeterminate
        matInverse(0, 1) = matTranspose(0, 1) / dDeterminate
        matInverse(0, 2) = matTranspose(0, 2) / dDeterminate
        matInverse(1, 0) = matTranspose(1, 0) / dDeterminate
        matInverse(1, 1) = matTranspose(1, 1) / dDeterminate
        matInverse(1, 2) = matTranspose(1, 2) / dDeterminate
        matInverse(2, 0) = matTranspose(2, 0) / dDeterminate
        matInverse(2, 1) = matTranspose(2, 1) / dDeterminate
        matInverse(2, 2) = matTranspose(2, 2) / dDeterminate

        vChange.X =
            (Math.Abs(_delta.X * matInverse(0, 0)) +
             Math.Abs(_delta.Y * matInverse(0, 1)) +
             Math.Abs(_delta.Z * matInverse(0, 2))) * negativeFactor
        vChange.Y =
            (Math.Abs(_delta.X * matInverse(1, 0)) +
             Math.Abs(_delta.Y * matInverse(1, 1)) +
             Math.Abs(_delta.Z * matInverse(1, 2))) * negativeFactor
        vChange.Z =
            (Math.Abs(_delta.X * matInverse(2, 0)) +
             Math.Abs(_delta.Y * matInverse(2, 1)) +
             Math.Abs(_delta.Z * matInverse(2, 2))) * negativeFactor

        Return vChange
    End Function
End Class

Public Class Vector
    Public Property X() As Single
    Public Property Y() As Single
    Public Property Z() As Single
    Public Sub New(ByVal _x As Single, ByVal _y As Single, ByVal _z As Single)
        X = _x
        Y = _y
        Z = _z
    End Sub
End Class
```

I've managed to re-factor this so far, but i am stuck on the matAdjoin

```
Private Function InverseVector(ByVal _delta As Vector3, ByVal _rotation As Vector3) As Vector3
    Dim vChange As New Vector3(0, 0, 0)
    Dim matX As Matrix4x4 = Matrix4x4.Identity
    Dim matY As Matrix4x4 = Matrix4x4.Identity
    Dim matZ As Matrix4x4 = Matrix4x4.Identity
    Dim negativeFactor As Int32 = 1
    Dim determinate As Single
    Dim matAdjoin As Matrix4x4
    Dim matTranspose As Matrix4x4
    Dim matInverse As Matrix4x4
    If _delta.X < 0 Or _delta.Y < 0 Or _delta.Z < 0 Then
        negativeFactor = -1
    End If
    'Load the X Matrix
    Dim sRadians As Single = 0.0174532D * _rotation.X
    matX = Matrix4x4.CreateRotationX(sRadians)
    matX.M23 *= -1
    matX.M32 *= -1
    'Load up the Y Matrix
    sRadians = 0.0174532D * _rotation.Y
    matY = Matrix4x4.CreateRotationY(sRadians)
    'Load up the Z Matrix
    sRadians = 0.0174532D * _rotation.Z
    matZ = Matrix4x4.CreateRotationZ(sRadians)
    matZ.M12 *= -1
    matZ.M21 *= -1
    'multiply the two matrices
    Dim resultMatrix1 As Matrix4x4 = Matrix4x4.Multiply(matX, matY)
    'Now mutiply ResultMatrix with X matrix
    Dim resultMatrix2 As Matrix4x4 = Matrix4x4.Multiply(matZ, resultMatrix1)
    'Get determinate
    determinate = resultMatrix2.GetDeterminant
    'stuck on from here on
    Return vChange
End Function
```

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is not about a specific programming problem, but rather presents a task for us to complete. If you want to get help on refactoring working code, you might visit http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, but be warned that they might not take kindly to being asked to doing all of your work for you, either.

Comment: So what is the System.Numerics method that performs the matAdjoin in the code?

Comment: well that code appears to be constructing -x, -y and -z rotation matrices. Then calculating the co-factor and the adjugate. looking at the source code for System.Numerics.Matrix4x4 it would appear Matrix4x4.Invert might be the correct call.

Answer (score 0):

this appears to be a solution. Although i am not happy about the multiplication of x,y,z by rows in the last 4 lines of the method.

```
Private Function InverseVector(ByVal _delta As Vector3, ByVal _rotation As Vector3) As Vector3
    Dim vChange As New Vector3(0, 0, 0)
    Dim negativeFactor As Int32 = 1
    Dim matAdjugate As Matrix4x4
    If _delta.X < 0 Or _delta.Y < 0 Or _delta.Z < 0 Then
        negativeFactor = -1
    End If
    Dim angle As Vector3 = _rotation * 0.0174532D
    'Load the -X Matrix
    Dim negativeRotationX As Matrix4x4 = Matrix4x4.CreateRotationX(angle.X)
    negativeRotationX.M23 *= -1
    negativeRotationX.M32 *= -1
    'Load up the -Y Matrix
    Dim negativeRotationY As Matrix4x4 = Matrix4x4.CreateRotationY(angle.Y)
    negativeRotationY.M21 *= -1
    'Load up the -Z Matrix
    Dim negativeRotationZ As Matrix4x4 = Matrix4x4.CreateRotationZ(angle.Z)
    negativeRotationZ.M12 *= -1
    negativeRotationZ.M21 *= -1
    'multiply the x,y matrices
    Dim resultMatrix1 As Matrix4x4 = Matrix4x4.Multiply(negativeRotationX, negativeRotationY)
    'Now mutiply z with x,y matrix
    Dim resultMatrix2 As Matrix4x4 = Matrix4x4.Multiply(negativeRotationZ, resultMatrix1)
    Dim can As Boolean = Matrix4x4.Invert(resultMatrix2, matAdjugate)
    vChange.X = (Math.Abs(_delta.X * matAdjugate.M11) + Math.Abs(_delta.Y * matAdjugate.M12) + Math.Abs(_delta.Z * matAdjugate.M13)) * negativeFactor
    vChange.Y = (Math.Abs(_delta.X * matAdjugate.M21) + Math.Abs(_delta.Y * matAdjugate.M22) + Math.Abs(_delta.Z * matAdjugate.M23)) * negativeFactor
    vChange.Z = (Math.Abs(_delta.X * matAdjugate.M31) + Math.Abs(_delta.Y * matAdjugate.M32) + Math.Abs(_delta.Z * matAdjugate.M33)) * negativeFactor
    Return vChange
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

this works too.

```
Private Function InverseVector(ByVal _delta As Vector3, ByVal _rotation As Vector3) As Vector3
    Dim vChange As New Vector3(0, 0, 0)
    Dim negativeFactor As Int32 = 1
    Dim matAdjugate As Matrix4x4
    If _delta.X < 0 Or _delta.Y < 0 Or _delta.Z < 0 Then
        negativeFactor = -1
    End If
    Dim angle As Vector3 = _rotation * 0.0174532D
    Dim negativeRotationX As Matrix4x4 = Matrix4x4.Negate(Matrix4x4.CreateRotationX(angle.X))
    Dim negativeRotationY As Matrix4x4 = Matrix4x4.Negate(Matrix4x4.CreateRotationY(angle.Y))
    Dim negativeRotationZ As Matrix4x4 = Matrix4x4.Negate(Matrix4x4.CreateRotationZ(angle.Z))
    'multiply the x,y matrices
    Dim resultMatrix1 As Matrix4x4 = Matrix4x4.Multiply(negativeRotationX, negativeRotationY)
    'Now mutiply z with x,y matrix
    Dim resultMatrix2 As Matrix4x4 = Matrix4x4.Multiply(negativeRotationZ, resultMatrix1)
    Dim can As Boolean = Matrix4x4.Invert(resultMatrix2, matAdjugate)
    vChange.X = (Math.Abs(_delta.X * matAdjugate.M11) + Math.Abs(_delta.Y * matAdjugate.M12) + Math.Abs(_delta.Z * matAdjugate.M13)) * negativeFactor
    vChange.Y = (Math.Abs(_delta.X * matAdjugate.M21) + Math.Abs(_delta.Y * matAdjugate.M22) + Math.Abs(_delta.Z * matAdjugate.M23)) * negativeFactor
    vChange.Z = (Math.Abs(_delta.X * matAdjugate.M31) + Math.Abs(_delta.Y * matAdjugate.M32) + Math.Abs(_delta.Z * matAdjugate.M33)) * negativeFactor
    Return vChange
End Function**strong text**
```